# What is an interface assertion?

Tags: go, interface, assertion

I have just came across this piece of code on [this blog post](https://tendermint.com/blog/abstracting-the-logger-interface-in-go?utm_source=golangweekly&utm_medium=email)

```
type Logger interface {
    Debug(msg string, keyvals ...interface{}) error
    Info(msg string, keyvals ...interface{}) error
    Error(msg string, keyvals ...interface{}) error
}

type tmLogger struct {
    srcLogger kitlog.Logger
}

// Interface assertions
var _ Logger = (*tmLogger)(nil) // What is this?

// ... interface definition ...
```

What is this "interface assertion"?

Comment: You're right, "interface assertion" isn't a thing, but it's not a type assertion either. Type assertions are exclusively `var.(Type)` form (as indicated in the doc you linked). This is a [type *conversion*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). /pedantic

Comment: @Adrian: oh yes, correct, it's definitely a type conversion I sort of glanced over the code and assumed a `.` in there because of the term "assertion"

Comment: Yeah calling it an interface assertion is too close to a real term, makes it more confusing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It assigns a nil pointer to a concrete type to a variable of the interface type. This is a common practice to prove that the concrete type fulfills the interface - if it doesn't, that line won't compile, giving an error that the concrete type can't be assigned to a variable of the interface type and why.

As @JimB noted, "interface assertion" is a term made up by the author. Go has no such term. This is, specifically, a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), converting `nil` to a pointer to `tmLogger`, then assigning the typed nil pointer to a [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) variable of the interface type `Logger`. If `*tmLogger` does not satisfy `Logger`, the assignment won't compile; but, at runtime, this takes no memory because it's using a nil value.

Presumably the author uses this term more in the unit-testing sense of "assertion" than the "type assertion" sense - that line of code asserts that the type implements the interface, and if it doesn't, the line will fail.

Given that this is purely a testing practice, personally I put these checks in _test.go files so that they're included in unit test executions, excluded from the final binary, and clearly part of the test suite and not the application logic.