# Is this a special form of Go type assertion?

Tags: go, syntax

I am a total novice Go programmer.

I ran across this in the Kubernetes source code:

```
var (
  _ = Queue(&FIFO{}) // FIFO is a Queue
)
```

`Queue` is declared earlier like this:

```
type Queue interface { // etc.
```

`FIFO` is declared earlier like this:

```
type FIFO struct { // etc.
```

So is my first excerpt a kind of type assertion?  It doesn't seem to fit the syntax described by [the Go Tour's lesson-let on the subject](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15).

I certainly can take it on faith that this block is ensuring that a `FIFO` "is a" `Queue`, but I want to understand exactly what's going on here, and I am too much of a novice to know where to look in the [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) (the [section on type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), which seems to be what this is semantically, didn't seem to cover this case, nor did the [section on interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976862/what-is-an-interface-assertion/44976881#44976881

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [Type Conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) which is a little different than a type assertion.

Comment: Thank you.  For any other rookies: it appears from the spec that `Queue(&FIFO{})`, which looks like some kind of weird function call to my Go-novice eyes, should be equivalent to `(Queue)(&FIFO{})`, which looks more like a typecast kind of construction and made it a little easier for me to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Furthermore, it looks like this is essentially playing the role of an assertion: it is effectively ensuring that the `FIFO` `struct`, no matter what maintainers might do to it, will always be "convertible" to a `Queue`.

Comment: Ya, this is functionally a compile-time assertion.  By converting a struct to an interface, it does a compile-time check to make sure the struct fulfills the interface, instead of simply panicking at run time if you boo-boo and break that interface fulfillment.  It's one of the recommended methods of ensuring your types fulfill the interfaces you think they do.  Another alternative is constructors that return structs as the interface in question, has the same compile-time effect.